# Wordpress redirect done wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this code? It doesn't work.

```php
add_action( 'ap_after_question_form_processed', function () {
  ap_ajax_json(
      array(
          'success'  => true,
          'redirect' => get_permalink( 'https://myscustomlink.com' ), // CHANGE THIS TO CUSTOM LINK
      )
  );
});
```

Comment: I've managed to find the problem. 

'redirect' => 'https://myscustomlink.com', // CHANGE THIS TO CUSTOM LINK

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add new information in comments.

Comment: Can you precise your issue and what you want ?